# Simple HTML Dom Space in attribute

Tags: php

my code is the following

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=this attribute]') as $itemtitle) {
    echo $itemtitle;
}
```

I have a space in the middle of the attribute and so my code seems to not be working. Is there a way to get around the space so it picks it up? The space as to stay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML class names actually cannot have spaces. Spaces delimit multiple classes, so you're actually giving the element two classes: `this` and `attribute`.

So, find elements with both classes. This should do the trick:

```
foreach($html->find('div.this.attribute') as $itemtitle) {
    echo $itemtitle;
}
```

(The `.` is a shorthand for class.)

---

Actually, your original code as posted will work fine. You've got an error somewhere else in your code—`$html` does not contain the necessary parsed HTML. Could you post that section of your code?

Comment: The class attribute can absolutely have spaces in it, however, class names cannot.

Comment: getting a "Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object" when I run it

Comment: @user, that's an issue with the code you're using to put the HTML into `$html`. And that's why you're having trouble: your code (as posted) should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just quote it:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class="this attribute"]') as $itemtitle) {
    echo $itemtitle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking at the class attribute you could use:

```
foreach($html->find('div.this.attribute') as $itemtitle) {
    echo $itemtitle;
}
```

Which will test that it has both the classes `this` and `attribute`, but not necessarily separated by a single space in the attribute (could have other classes in between, before, and after, and the order may be reversed like `class="attribute this"`).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
find('div[class="this attribute"]')
```